# Is there any way to restrict the output of an XSLT to a specific number of records?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm barely a novice at XSLT - I'm essentially a web designer who is hacking at a file I was given by developers who no longer work at the company. Here's the code I'm working with (minus a bunch of fields just to keep the example simple). It converts a list of job openings into XML.

I would like to devise a way to prevent the feed from including more than a set number of `<job>` results in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl in lang user" xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0" xmlns:lang="http://www.composite.net/ns/localization/1.0" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Web" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Web" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Net" />
<![CDATA[

public string HTMLDecode(string JoDesc) {
 string jd = JoDesc;
 jd = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(jd);
 return jd;
}
]]>
  </msxsl:script>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="jobs">
      <xsl:for-each select="//Results">
        <xsl:variable name="allElementsExist">
          <xsl:if test=".//PositionId and JobDescription">
            <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$allElementsExist = 'true'">
          <xsl:element name="job">
            <xsl:element name="client_job_id">
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of
                select=".//PositionId"
                disable-output-escaping="yes"
              />
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="description">
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of
                select="user:HTMLDecode(JobDescription)"
                disable-output-escaping="yes"
              />
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried fiddling with position(), which failed because it was counting every looped record and not just those that made it through as `<job>` elements in the output. I also tried using a counter, but as I have learned, there's no such thing as re-setting a variable within XSLT. I read some of the other posts on here about counts, but they don't appear to apply when there are `if:test`s involved and I keep coming up with wrong numbers.

Is there anything I can do in this scenario? Perhaps a way to increment a variable by using my scripts? I saw some other posts about using an 'extension' but I didn't really understand how to implement that.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Your question is not clear because we don't see what your input looks like nor what the expected output is.  And removing those parts of code that are irrelevant to the problem would also help - see [mcve].  I am guessing you want to do something along the lines of `<xsl:for-each select="something[someCondition][position() &lt; someNumber]">`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way of limiting the number of elements in the output, but it's easy to limit the number of elements you process from the input, and in your example that seems to amount to the same thing.

You're doing:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//Results">
    <xsl:variable name="allElementsExist">
      <xsl:if test=".//PositionId and JobDescription">
        <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$allElementsExist = 'true'">
```

which is a very convoluted way of doing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Results[.//PositionId and JobDescription]">
```

and you can limit the number of `job` elements output to `$limit` by extending this to

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Results
      [.//PositionId and JobDescription]
      [position() &lt; $limit]">
```

By the way, this is horrible XSLT code you've inherited, but we'll ignore that as it's not really relevant to your question.

Comment: I think we are in agreement on the quality of the XSLT! ;) It was written by someone who didn't know what they were doing and I, a person who knows even less, have been maintaining it. At some point it'll all get tossed in favor of a proper setup. For now, I'll give your suggestion a crack though - thanks!